# What can I do to receive my money?

Tags: job-offer

I worked for a temporary agency. The company I was placed at offered me the job permanently on March 12th, and I received an offer letter on March 15th. However, this offer letter had several substantial details incorrect. I spoke with the regional manager and the property manager and they both assured me that it will be corrected immediately. However, my temp agency was never informed that the company wanted to hire me.

I continued to request the corrected offer letter, but my manager told me to corporate office. I left messages and sent emails; no response. I was told to attend training at corporate office, which I did -- but in the middle of this, I found out that they had changed their mind about hiring me.

I went to corporate to see what could be done, but I got the run-around. I turned down 2 other job offers during this mayhem. One of the managers said that she would pay me my commission, but she has not contacted me since. What can I do?

Comment: _left messages and emails_ If the writing of your e-mails were like this question, I am afraid you'll need to re-write them. I tried to read this question a few times, I could not understand it.

Comment: I agree -- I suggested an edit based on my understanding, but I'm sure I didn't do it justice. Frankly, your communication skills may have contributed to the adverse decision you describe.

Answer (score 2):

> What can I do?

**About getting the job back** -- very little. You've been working on this for weeks and things are moving in the wrong direction. Either this company is dysfunctional or you are not a good fit, but either way, I doubt this will come together.

**About getting your money** -- make sure you are actually owed money -- I'm assuming you have no contract. It seems like your training should be paid at least. If necessary, you can sue in small claims court.

**About the jobs you turned down** -- you can try recontacting these jobs to see if the openings remain. I'm sure you learned the lesson that you should never turn down a job until your other job is finalized.

**To avoid this happening again** -- don't begin work until you are officially on payroll. Don't turn down other job offers until you are officially on payroll. Continue to acquire skills and better yourself.